# How to order or choose rows in MySQL GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
id       number    otherfields
-------------------------------------------
664      48       aaa
665      49       bbb
666      55       ccc
667      48       ddd
```

My query groups by the `number` field, and I want it to pick the first (lowest) `id`, so that the data comes out like `ccc,aaa,bbb` (when ordered by `number`). However I'm getting `ccc,ddd,bbb` - in other words, it's picking row #667 instead of #664 for the number 48.

Oddly, this only happens on the live server; on localhost I get it the correct way even though the table is exactly the same (exported from localhost, imported onto server).

Is it possible to ensure that the `GROUP BY` clause picks the first ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible in MySQL. You have to use a join.

```
SELECT id, number, otherfields FROM table 
  WHERE id in (SELECT min(id) FROM table GROUP BY number)
```

Comment: I get an error with that: *"#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"* - I'm guessing because the subquery returns 2 fields but you're only looking for 1 (the id).

Comment: Ah - just removing the number field from the sub-query appears to work. You don't specifically need it for the sub-query, do you? It does appear to be several times slower, though (0.3s as opposed to 0.001s for most queries).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - fixed, thanks. I guess jms's answer maybe faster. Haven't do any benchmark.

Comment: I indexed my `number` field and the performance has improved somewhat. I'm caching all pages anyway so it will only be that tiny bit slower once an hour :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL-92 version.

```
SELECT 
     id, number, otherfields 
FROM 
     table t
     join (SELECT min(id) as id, number FROM table GROUP BY number) sq --subquery
       on t.id = sq.id
```