# GROUP BY to select records with monthly periodic dates

Tags: mysql

I'm working with stock price data and making this query to get one price per month for, say, Google (from a table with prices for every weekday):

`SELECT * FROM pricedata WHERE symbol='GOOG' GROUP BY symbol,month(date),year(date)`

```
2012-07-02
2012-06-01
2012-05-01
```

If I remove the WHERE clause it returns the last date of the month instead of the first (and more rows because all the symbols in the table show up, of course), as in

`SELECT * FROM pricedata GROUP BY symbol,month(date),year(date)`

```
2012-07-31
2012-06-29
2012-05-31
```

I understand that 'The server is free to choose any value from each group', so I'm probably just lucky that the first query works as I want, but I'd like to know why the change occurs.

Is there a fast solution to consistently get the first value of each month? I haven't found any similar questions, but they might be out there... The second query isn't vital but I was trying to build a reduced-size table for monthly-only records and ran into this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938918/how-to-order-or-choose-rows-in-mysql-group-by-clause - Get the date of the first day per month and then select (join) all data you need for these dates/days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know why the change occurs.

The server is free to choose any value from the group, but in practice it chooses the first it finds. If you have an index on `symbol` then it will choose the first one as they are sorted in the index. If you remove the `WHERE` clause it will use another index or the clustered key. This will be sorted in a different order, and therefore the first row the server encounters will be different.

Basically you should not ever rely on getting any specific value. As the documentation says, the server is free to choose any value and which value it chooses is not specified.

> Is there a fast solution to consistently get the first value of each month?

```
SELECT symbol, MIN(date) AS date
FROM pricedata
GROUP BY symbol, month(date), year(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.
It's a bit more complicated, because I need the rest of the columns (price, volume) that go along with the date retrieved by MIN(date)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the "greatest per group". You can get that by joining the above result with your original table.

Comment: That seems to be working correctly, takes about 40% longer than your original query, but speed isn't a concern. Just to confirm, is this what you had in mind?

    `SELECT p.* from pricedata p
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT symbol, Max(date) AS date
    FROM pricedata
    GROUP BY symbol, month(date), year(date)
    ) j
    WHERE p.symbol=j.symbol AND p.date=j.date`

Comment: @cryocide: Yes, though I'd use ON rather than WHERE for clarity. It should make no difference to either the correctness of the result or the performance though.